# How to join table to show multiple data?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter. I have a problem
I have two tables **Set** and **Subject**

**Set** has column ***Id, Set_name*** and **Subject** has column ***id, subject_name,set_id***

I want to show dara as below image

[image: I have to add data like below image]

i used following code

controller

`$where=array('user_id'=>$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
     $val=array('id','set_name','desc','status');
     $data['set']=$this->login->get_where2($val,$where,'q_set');
     $select=array('id','name','set_id');
     $data['sub']=$this->login->get_some($select,'subject');
     $data['msg']=$this->session->flashdata('msg');
     $this->load->view('admin/header');
     $this->load->view('i_user/setlist',$data);
     $this->load->view('admin/sidebar');`

view

`<tbody>
    <?php foreach($set as $setdata){?>
    <tr>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $setdata->set_name;?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php foreach($sub as $subdata){ if($subdata->set_id==$setdata->id){?><span class='subject'><?php echo $subdata->name;?></span><?php }}?><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>user/subject" style="float:right;">Add Subject</a></td>
   <td class="center"><?php if($setdata->status==1){echo 'Published';}else{echo 'Unpublished';}?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php }?> 
    </tbody>`

This code is working well, but i think there is some unnecessary loops are running to show subject name. Is there any other way to do this? If yes then please suggest. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Set has column *Id, Set_name* and Subject has column *id, subject_name,set_id*`

```
$this->db->select('Set.Set_name,Subject.subject_name');
$this->db->from('Set');
$this->db->join('Subject','Subject.set_id=Set.id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->run();
```

Try this.It's a left join between both tables.